# Python - How to save a matplotlib figure in super high resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib, resolution

I have a geoplot with over 1.3 million datapoints. I would like to save this figure in super super high resolution if possible. Using dpi controls and figure settings in matplotlib does not seem to be achieving this.

This is the image I'm trying to make:
[image]

Comment: We may need additional information here. What have you tried so far - and where does `medium high resolution` end and `super high resolution` start.

Comment: Are you explicitly passing in the dpi to `savefig`?  If you're just setting `fig.dpi`, then it will actually be overridden when saving with `savefig` (the default dpi for `savefig` is 100).

Comment: I am using plt.savefig('uk_postcodes.svg', format='svg', dpi=3000) to set dpi.                                                                If the dpi exceeds around 3000, I get: ValueError: width and height must each be below 32768. By super high resolution I'm meaning as large as physically possible.                                                           To provide context, I am plotting every postcode in the UK to their corresponding lat and long coordinates.

Comment: @SamuelBancroft - That's a limitation of the Antigrain renderer (i.e. the third-party library that's used for the matplotlib `*Agg` backends).  You might be able to get around it by switching to another backend (e.g. `Cairo` or `GDK`, if you have either of those available) or by saving to a vector format (e.g. `pdf`/`svg`/`ps`/`eps`/etc).  For what it sounds like you're doing, a vector format might make more sense.

Comment: @JoeKington - why not post your comment as an answer? Especially with the part about vector graphics.

Comment: How do you plan to look at this figure?  How are you making the figure?  Is this an image (via imshow) or a scatter plot or what?  Some things play very badly with the vector backends (like raster images where you end up drawing a rectangle for every pixel, specified via ascii).

Comment: @tcaswell If the figure is a high resolution image such as a jpeg, I have existing scripts to view it in a google-maps viewer. Unfortunately I'm struggling to increase the pixel dimensions beyond 24,000, and there seems to be a limit to the minimum marker point size...

Comment: google-maps should (I would expect) be able to deal with tiles as well, I would go that route.